# How to make an WIdeChar array as empty in Delphi 7?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have a WideChar array . I would like to make it empty ( currently filled with garbage ) .
  I want to know how to do this with a WideChar array as we do it with a char array with  = #0;

Thanks in Advance

Comment: i will answer it myself . FillChar( ArrName , SizeOf(ArrName) , #0) is the way to do it.

Comment: Please post your comment as an actual answer, and then you can mark it as accepted. This won't earn you any rep, but it will tell people you've gotten an answer and make it easier for people who find your question in a search later to see the answer, too. Answering your own question is acceptable here; see the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for guidelines. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The delphi  function `FillChar` is the way to do it . If you have an array named `Arr1` , simply use `FillChar(Arr1,SizeOf(Arr1),#0)` to accomplish the goal.